# Why i capture more than one time but the app pick only first picture to process

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, camera

I have two activity one is for take an image and another is process image. but i found the problem that when i take a photo for more than one time. The picture that is processed is still an the first one. why it not change picture. and how i can fix it.

this is a first activity for take an image
    public class CaptureCamera extends Activity {

```
Camera mCamera = null; 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_start); 
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    Preview mPreview = new Preview(this, mCamera); 
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cam_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenCenterX = (size.x /4);
    int screenCenterY = (size.y/6) ;

    //Adding listener
    ImageView captureButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

            }
        });

  //Adding listener
    ImageView backButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(CaptureCamera.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

    //Adding listener
    ImageView nextButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button_next);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(CaptureCamera.this, ProcessPic.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        });
} 
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera camera = null;

    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        // cannot get camera or does not exist
    }
    return camera;
}
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
         File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null){
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                Toast.makeText(CaptureCamera.this, "Photo saved to folder \"sdcard\\DCIM\\CameraSnap\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
    }
};

private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "CameraSnap");
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("CameraSnap", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    };
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +"IMG_0"+".jpg");


   return mediaFile;
    }    
} 

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
SurfaceHolder mHolder; 
Camera mCamera; 
Preview(Context context, Camera camera) { 
    super(context); 
    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when 
    this.mCamera = camera;
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed. 
    mHolder = getHolder(); 
    mHolder.addCallback(this); 
  //this is a deprecated method, is not required after 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
} 

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell 
    // to draw. 

    try {

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
} 


public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the 
    // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, 
    // important to release it when the activity is paused. 
    mCamera.stopPreview(); 
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null; 

} 

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) { 
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters 
    // the preview. 
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
    Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);


    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.startPreview();

}

}
```

Here is Process Activity that will get image from DCIM/capturesnap and calculate HSV color
But when i have take second picture and then click button to this activity. the output (HSV color) that is shown is still belong to the old picture.
How i can fix it, in order to process picture in the last picture not the old one.

```
public class ProcessPic extends Activity {


public static ArrayList<Double> HueValue = new ArrayList<Double>(9);
public static int xImage,yImage,red,green,blue,RR,Y,B;
public static float[] hsv = new float[3];
public static Bitmap myBitmapPic,myBitmapPic1;
public static double a,b,r,std_err = 0.0;
public static double e;
public static int N;
//Variable for Vmode
public static int Rred,Ggreen,Bblue, maxCount;
static float maxValue;
public static float[] hsvMode = new float[3];
public static int[] ModeValue = new int[17415];//rare data
public static double[] HueValueMode = new double[17415];//rare data




public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_process);

    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ 
    File imgFile = new File(path);


    myBitmapPic1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());                  
    //resize
    Bitmap myBitmapPic = null;
    myBitmapPic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmapPic1, 2560, 1920, true);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageAdd);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmapPic);


    //0
    ProcessPic h1ppm = new ProcessPic();
    h1ppm.AverageColor(myBitmapPic, 244,395,1198,1388);
    HueValue.add((double) hsv[0]);

    ProcessPic model = new ProcessPic();
    model.Regression(x, y);
    tv1.setText(hsv[0]);


    //Adding listener
    ImageView backButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBack);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProcessPic.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    //Adding listener
    ImageView nextButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageSave);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(ProcessPic.this, AddStudent.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent1);

            }
        });

}

public static void AverageColor (Bitmap myBitmap,int minw, int maxw,int minh, int maxh){//for master color

    red = 0;
    green = 0;
    blue = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=minw;i<maxw;i++){
        for (int j=minh;j<maxh;j++){
            int pixel = myBitmap.getPixel(i,j);

            red += pixel >> 16 & 0xFF;
            green += pixel >> 8 & 0xFF;
            blue += pixel & 0xFF;

            count++;        

        }
    }
    red /= count;
    green /= count;
    blue /= count;

    //---------------------convert RGB to HSV----------------//
    int avgRed = red;
    int avgGreen = green;
    int avgBlue = blue;

    Color.RGBToHSV(avgRed,avgGreen,avgBlue,hsv);
    //float hue = hsv[0];
    //float saturate = hsv[1];
    //float brightness = hsv[2];
}

public static void ValueArray (Bitmap myBitmap,int minw, int maxw,int minh, int maxh) {//for หลุม

    Rred = 0;
    Ggreen = 0;
    Bblue = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i=minw;i<maxw;i++){
        for (int j=minh;j<maxh;j++){
            int pixel = myBitmap.getPixel(i,j);
            Rred = pixel >> 16 & 0xFF;
            Ggreen = pixel >> 8 & 0xFF;         
            Bblue = pixel & 0xFF;           
            ProcessPic.RGBtoHSV(Rred, Ggreen, Bblue, hsvMode);
            //Color.RGBToHSV(Rred,Ggreen,Bblue,hsvMode);
            //create V array
            //ModeValue[count] = (int)(hsvMode[2]*100);//ทำไมตรงนี้ค่ามันมากกว่า [0...1]
            //HueValueMode[count] =  hsvMode[0];
            ModeValue[count] = (int)(hsvMode[2]*100);
            HueValueMode[count] =  hsvMode[0];
            //can create h at this
            count++;
        }
    }
}


public static int Mode(int a[]) {//ModeValue[]

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; ++j) {
            if (a[j] == a[i]) 
                    ++count;
        }
        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = a[i];
        }
    }

    return (int) maxValue;
}


public static double averagehuemode(int a[]) {//ModeValue[]
    double temp=0;
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            if (a[i] >= maxValue-5 && a[i] <= maxValue+5){//เลขตรงนี้
                temp+= HueValueMode[i];
                count++;
            }
    }

    return temp/count;
}


public static void RGBtoHSV(int r, int g, int b, float[] hsvMode){

    double h, s, v;

    double min, max, delta;

    min = Math.min(Math.min(r, g), b);
    max = Math.max(Math.max(r, g), b);

    // V
    v = max/255;

     delta = max - min;

    // S
     if( max != 0 )
        s = delta / max;
     else {
        s = 0;
        h = -1;
        //return new double[]{h,s,v};
     }

    // H
     if( r == max )
        h = ( g - b ) / delta; // between yellow & magenta
     else if( g == max )
        h = 2 + ( b - r ) / delta; // between cyan & yellow
     else
        h = 4 + ( r - g ) / delta; // between magenta & cyan

     h *= 60;    // degrees

    if( h < 0 )
        h += 360;

    hsvMode[0] = (int)(h);
    hsvMode[1] = (float)(s);
    hsvMode[2] = (float)(v);

}
```

Comment: `String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ ` - looks like a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: How should i do? Is there any code to reset it or have to change code.

Comment: Please check, your code does not compile!

Answer (score 2):

Few points to consider:

1. After calling Camera.takePicture(), preview stops, so ["to take more photos, call startPreview() first"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) - do in after saving image in onPictureTaken(), eg:

   ```
   try {
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
       fos.write(data);
       fos.close();
       Toast.makeText(CaptureCamera.this, "Photo saved to folder \"sdcard\\DCIM\\CameraSnap\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       //start preview to take more pictures
       mCamera.startPreview();
   ```
2. Do not swallow exceptions - if something goes wrong, you won't know it. Add printStackTrace() in onPictureTaken():

   ```
   try {
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
       fos.write(data);
       fos.close();
       Toast.makeText(CaptureCamera.this, "Photo saved to folder \"sdcard\\DCIM\\CameraSnap\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       //start preview to take more pictures
       mCamera.startPreview();

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
3. When calling other activities, instead of:

   ```
   Intent intent1 = new Intent(CaptureCamera.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
   finish();
   startActivity(intent1);
   ```

call finish() last, so:

```
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(CaptureCamera.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
    finish();
```

Comment: i'm already follower you, i've never know before that add start preview to take more pictures. very thank you. but my aim is still occur. I don't want to take picture more than one in near time. but i want that when i take a photo (i can take a photo one time) and click next it will show the result of the previous picture. and if i back to take a photo again it will show the result again with the last picture. but now when i take a second photo and click next. it show the old result, it not change. why does it is and how i can fix it.